# Adding semantic markup to a rails application / RDFa

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, rdfa

I am surprised to see little information about this. I'd like to enhance my Rails webpages with semantic markup for use with Facebook/LinkedIn/Twitter and Search Engines.

Most things I find when typing "RDFA ruby/rails" are actually processors that can read/parse graphs and schemas, but not actually assist including semantic markup in a website.

I am wondering how people actually do this ? By passing RDFa in html_options in content_tag ? By manually adding this in the HTML views ?

I actually found [this gem](http://rdfa.rubyforge.org/) that seems to do that, but it's not on github, and the page seems to date from the pre-bootstrap era where people wrote raw html (if I may). There is no indication of activity on this gem, no single date on that page, and the download seems to be broken.

Is it something so uncommon for Rails websites to have semantic markup ??

EDIT :

Using Rails 5 and Mongoid, and will be using Algolia soon

Comment: I don't find it that strange that you're not finding that much- RDFa was kinda a thing back in 2008. It  tanked when the whole idea of (x)html as the interchange format of the web died in favor of JSON apis.
Semantic markup is one thing - rich document formats have not really delivered on the intended promise beyond simple stuff like vcard.

Comment: I actually got in touch with the guy who released that RDFa gem. I'm trying to get him to post his code on github ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually there are some gems that will do what you want, like `green_monkey` and `item`, but unfortunately they are not actively maintained:

https://github.com/Paxa/green_monkey

https://github.com/lassebunk/item

also if you want to parse or extract `microdata` from html files you can use `mida`:

https://github.com/LawrenceWoodman/mida

and the `meta-tags` gem looks interesting and worth checking out :

https://github.com/kpumuk/meta-tags/

Comment: Thanks for the references. I like the meta-tags gem, but it is focuses on just meta tags, doesn't go well with search pages for example, where several results need to be semantized.